# How to test AngularJS controller using Karma-Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to use Jasmine and karma to set up unit tests like explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing), in my already developed Angularjs application.

I created a simple test file for my controller like this:

```
describe('controller test', function() {
    beforeEach(module('ipaApp'));

    var $controller, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter
        // names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));
    describe('$scope.grade', function() {
        it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars',
                function() {
                    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                    var controller = $controller('reportViewCardController', {
                        $scope : $scope
                    });
                    $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
                    $scope.grade();
                    expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
                });
    });
});
```

and following is my karma.conf.js

```
 // Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Dec 31 2017 19:51:09 GMT+0530 (IST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    '/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js',
    '/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular-mocks.js',
    '/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular-route.js',
    '/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/app/*',
    '/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/test/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    '/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/app/app.module.js',
    '/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular-cron-generator.min.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

But on running karma with `karma start` I am getting following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMock due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24asyncCallbackProvider
        at /home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:68:12
        at /home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:4397:19
        at Object.getService [as get] (/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:4550:39)
        at Object.decorator (/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:4472:41)
        at /home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular-mocks.js:1842:12
        at Object.invoke (/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:4604:19)
        at runInvokeQueue (/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:4497:35)
        at /home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:4506:11
        at forEach (/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:321:20)
        at loadModules (/home/manoj/Desktop/workspace-development/dec-release/22-dec-17/bil-ipa/bil-ipa-ui/bil-ipa-ui-apm/src/main/webapp/resources/js/libs/angularjs/angular.js:4487:5)
```

Even after including ngMock dependency is not being resolved. What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Hi, please provide controller function?